# Genetic algorithms learn to best fit an exponential function

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

So I have a simple game where a ball can jump and obstacles come at it in a regular fashion, a picture is below for reference. My genetic algorithm provides 100 random networks, 20 crossover (mutation rate at 1%) and 10 'fuzzed' networks (essentially forced mutations at a rate of about 20%). 
[image]
Now if I have a basic non-scaling movement speed for my periodic obstacles my genetic algorithm learns how to beat the game (simply wont lose and continues forever) in about 1-2 generations, since this is a simple mapping of x->y that's to be expected.

However if I decide to change my speed scaling (for both jump/obstacle speed) to say

```
speed = speed * (1 + points/1000) #Where 1 point is passing 1 obstacle
```

What I get is a large amount of networks that fail to optimize the output in any real time frame. I make sure to pass in all dependent data as my input nodes; ball.y (since the ball doesn't move in the x), obstacle.x, obstacle.speed, ball.jumpspeed and the output is a single node for 1/jump, 0/do nothing.

Heres an example output of some generations, given by fitness

```
Generation 1    HIGH: 0.425    LOW: 0.000    AVG:0.1724547451001511
Generation 2    HIGH: 0.425    LOW: 0.165    AVG:0.17874677670683908
Generation 3    HIGH: 1.396    LOW: 0.165    AVG:0.19673599387987226
Generation 4    HIGH: 2.549    LOW: 0.165    AVG:0.2383717001862799
Generation 5    HIGH: 2.549    LOW: 0.166    AVG:0.236279356056333
Generation 6    HIGH: 2.549    LOW: 0.166    AVG:0.2173996155501196
Generation 7    HIGH: 2.549    LOW: 0.167    AVG:0.20148711858181925
Generation 8    HIGH: 2.549    LOW: 0.167    AVG:0.1985246675827307
 ...
Generation 69    HIGH: 2.549    LOW: 0.167    AVG:0.31935190938788394
Generation 70    HIGH: 2.549    LOW: 0.167    AVG:0.22603314425367058
Generation 71    HIGH: 2.549    LOW: 0.167    AVG:0.21650311863741362
Generation 72    HIGH: 2.549    LOW: 0.166    AVG:0.2258790184428012
```

I do understand that genetic algorithms essentially rely on random improvements but I would like to know if it is normal for large periods of stagnation to occur on such a 'simple' problem? I may just be jumping the gun, I wrote the whole network/game from scratch and I'm pretty sure it's working as is but I'm slightly unconvinced by the results, does anyone with more of a background in this sort of thing think that my results are pretty standard?

Also to show a code example would require about 500 lines minimum so I figure it probably isn't a good idea to post it.

Edit:
Right after I posted this I received another decent increase to my generations, I'm actively running this code to attempt to see if my model can learn to become 'perfect' at this.

```
Generation 83    HIGH: 2.549    LOW: 0.841    AVG:0.908536733716079
Generation 84    HIGH: 2.549    LOW: 0.839    AVG:0.9262430139422534
Generation 85    HIGH: 8.784    LOW: 0.842    AVG:0.9670151588313797
```

**EDIT**:Here is a link to the basic version hosted on github, in the version I uploaded if you read the testdata.txt you can see that the inputs are binary strings that are just trying to get multiplied by 2 as the expected output. I don't understand why it's not currently able to figure out what the exact output needs to be, and *be forewarned the code is incredibly ugly once you get down to the actual testing, everything needs to be re-structured.* https://github.com/TylerJohnson44/PyNN

If anyone can show me where my code fails to be a proper NN with a proper applied GA I'd appreciate it.